# CSS and JS of Bootstrap Toggle are not working after UpdatePanel was triggered in Asp.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel

Do you have any ideas on how the JS and CSS of Bootstrap toggle ([www.bootstraptoggle.com](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com)) will work after an UpdatePanel trigger in ASP.net?

I tried `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()` and `pageLoad` but it did not load.
Please see the images:

**Initial Load: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG6At.png

**After UpdatePanel trigger: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ib1G1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - the secret is to create a function that you want to run each time a page is loaded - and use add_pageLoaded to make sure it's called after an async postback too.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){        
        docReadyHandler();
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(
           docReadyHandler
        );
    });
    
    function docReadyHandler(){
        // code you want to run when the document is ready
    }
</script>
```

You can also set it in codebehind

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.UpdatePanel, GetType(string), "startupScript", "docReadyHandler();", true)
```